# Is it possible for linux to have a smooth booting process?

Tags: linux, boot, xorg

When I boot any GNU/Linux distribution (tried it with ubuntu and OpenSUSE), the booting process goes like this:

- POST
- grub
- ugly text dumping, usually loading dæmons
- splash screen
- tty prompt flickers, because it's set to auto login
- then it flickers to the DM
- then it flickers to the actual desktop

So, a lot of text I don't want to see and a lot of flickering. I wonder if it's because of a technical restriction that would require a complete redesign of some parts of the system (X, for example) or because developers are too lazy? Windows and Mac OS X get it right, so I know it's possible.

Comment: It's possible, Ubuntu does it.

Comment: Ask yourself whether it really matters and whether it's really worth wasting developer time on such a trivial feature. How often do you boot? How long does your boot process take? With an SSD and systemd, your boot process will be ~2-5 seconds....who cares if the resolution is changed once or twice during that time?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is Kernel Mode Setting and you'll want to load it as early as possible by including your graphic card's module in your initramfs image. Also, be sure to disable any `vga=` or `video=` arguments in your kernel line and disable any framebuffer driver as these will all conflict with KMS.